# DBCC CHECKDB Estimation Alternative

Tags: tempdb, dbcc

I am in the process of rolling out DBCC CHECKDB across our instances.

Each database will eventually either have a DBCC CHECKDB or DBCC CHECKDB PHYSICAL_ONLY.

The way I have been gauging whether a FULL CHECKDB should be done, or a PHYSICAL_ONLY is by examining the results from DBCC CHECKDB WITH ESTIMATEONLY.

However I ran this yesterday on SQL Server 2008 (SP1) and the tempdb estimation for a certain database was 510MB.

However in practice it filled the entire 19GB drive so the estimation was way off!

I was under the impression the ESTIMATEONLY bug was in SQL 2008 R2, not the standard 2008 ?

Is there another way to gauge tempdb usage? Some sort of database size to tempdb usage ratio: (I.e if I have a 500GB database how much tempdb consumption should I be expecting?)

I also need to implement test restores because we don't do that here. Once I have that server in place I will switch to PHYSICAL_ONLY for everything then do a full CHECKDB on the restored database.

Thank you

Comment: Did you had chance to read http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-does-dbcc-checkdb-with-estimateonly-work/ and I would first ask you to apply SP4 for 2008

Comment: I have yeah. I don't think it really helps in this case. "It’s supposed to be a very conservative estimate, but certain pathological cases can trip it up as it can’t account for all possible schemas." So if it does trip up is there another way?

Comment: IIRC there was bug in SQL Server where it used to do wrong estimation for checkdb I strongly suggest you to aply Sp4 and do estimation again. I am not aware of alternatives

Answer (score 3):

What we do to estimate the usage of tempdb and its size is to track its growth via data tracked in tables for a period of time before reboot happens as a part of maintenance activity.

P.S note: It may not be an alternative, but helps in tracking how tempdb grows over a period of time

Step 1 Create table to store the data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempDBFileSize] (
[TFSID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
[FileID] [int] NULL ,
[File_Logical_Name] [varchar] (128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
[State_Desc] [varchar] (128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
[Type_Desc] [varchar] (128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
[Default_File_SizeMB] [int] NULL ,
[ActualKB] [int] NULL ,
[ActualMB] [int] NULL ,
[File_MaxSize] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
[File_Growth] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
[Growth_Type] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Physical_File_Name] [varchar] (128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[DateCaptured] [datetime] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TempDBFileSize] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
CONSTRAINT [PK_TempDBFileSize] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[TFSID]
) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO
```

Step 2 Create SP to catch the tempdb data and log file usage within above created table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spTempdbFileSize
AS
/*
------------------------------------------------------
-- Object Name: dbo.spTempdbFileSize
-- Project: SQL Server TempDB Sizing
-- Business Process: SQL Server Capacity Planning
-- Purpose: Capture the TempDB growth
-- Detailed Description: Capture the TempDB size, name, file, etc for the TempDB files
-- Database: TempDB
-- Dependent Objects: dbo.TempDBFileSize
-- Called By: Admin - TempDB Sizing
-- Upstream Systems: None
-- Downstream Systems: None
-- 
------------------------------------------------------
-- Rev | CMR | Date Modified | Developer | Change Summary
------------------------------------------------------
-- 001 | N\A | 12.02.2007 | Edgewood | Original code
-- 002 |     | 03.30.2009 | Penberth | Modified the code to get the actual size
--                                     of the tempdb alongside the the default sizes.
--                                     Added the ActualKB and ActualMB columns and 
--                                     renamed the [File_SizeMB] to [Default_File_SizeMB]
--
*/
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO dbo.TempDBFileSize (FileID, File_Logical_Name, State_Desc, Type_Desc,
[Default_File_SizeMB], ActualKB, ActualMB, File_MaxSize, File_Growth, Growth_Type,
Physical_File_Name, DateCaptured)
SELECT File_ID,
MasterTbl.[Name],
MasterTbl.State_Desc,
MasterTbl.Type_Desc,
(MasterTbl.[Size] * 8)/1024 AS 'File_SizeMB',
(TempTbl.[size]*8) AS ActualKB, 
(TempTbl.[size]*8)/1024 as ActualMB,
File_MaxSize = CASE 
WHEN MasterTbl.[Max_Size] = 0 THEN 'NoGrowth'
WHEN MasterTbl.[Growth] = 0 THEN 'NoGrowth'
WHEN MasterTbl.[Max_Size] = -1 THEN 'UnlimitedGrowth'
WHEN MasterTbl.[Max_Size] = 268435456 THEN 'TLogMax'
ELSE CAST((MasterTbl.[Max_Size] * 8)/1024 AS varchar(10)) END,
File_Growth = CASE 
WHEN MasterTbl.[Growth] = 0 THEN 'NoGrowth'
WHEN MasterTbl.[Growth] > 0 AND MasterTbl.[is_percent_growth] = 0 
THEN CAST((MasterTbl.[Growth]* 8)/1024 AS varchar(10))
WHEN MasterTbl.[Growth] > 0 AND MasterTbl.[is_percent_growth] = 1 
THEN CAST(MasterTbl.[Growth] AS varchar(10))
ELSE 'Unknown' END,
Growth_Type = CASE
WHEN MasterTbl.[Growth] = 0 THEN 'NoGrowth'
WHEN MasterTbl.[is_percent_growth] = 0 THEN 'MegaBytes'
WHEN MasterTbl.[is_percent_growth] = 1 THEN 'Percentage'
ELSE 'Unknown' END,
MasterTbl.[Physical_Name],
GETDATE() AS 'DateCaptured'
FROM Master.sys.master_files MasterTbl (NOLOCK) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEMPDB.SYS.SYSFILES TempTbl (NOLOCK) 
 ON MasterTbl.[Physical_Name] = TempTbl.[filename]
WHERE Database_ID = 2
SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Step 3: Execute the above SP via SQL agent job: we schedule it to run every 4 hours. Therefore by the end of the week we have enough data to predict how much tempdb is growing and thus estimating accordingly.

Just execute

```
    SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[TempDBFileSize]
ORDER BY ActualMB
```

to view the stored results

Comment: Perhaps add a suggested ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Thanks for this. I shall implement the same or similar and see what the growth looks like